# Problems running Flink tutorial RideCleansing

Tags: java, apache-flink, data-stream

#### Hi my Flink friends,

I have several problems regarding the execution of my first Apache Flink Job. I did all the steps of this "1-handsOn-Tutorial":
https://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/dataStream/1-handsOn.html

I worked with **IntelliJ** (at the end I used the sample solution "RideCleansing.java"), build the JAR via **Maven** succesfully (mvn clean package), downloaded the sample data and **started Flink** (./bin/start-local.bat).

#### I tried 2 ways to start the Flink program:

1. **From command line**

`./bin/flink run -c com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.basics.RideCleansing /path/flink-training-exercises/target/flink-training-exercises-0.5.jar --input file:///Users/full_user_name/Downloads/nycTaxiRides.gz`

But following error occurs:

```
    ./bin/flink: line 55: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

So I think here are some problems with the whitespace between "Program Files"... My JAVA_HOME is referring to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 . What do you mean is wrong here?

2. **From Web Dashboard**
   I uploaded the flink-training-exercises-0.5.jar under the "Submit new Job" panel, referred to the main class and refer to the sample data.

In this case the program runs a step further but ends with an exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 58 more
```

Can you tell me what's wrong and what's going on here? Did I forgot some steps? Why this joda class can't be found?

Comment: Not sure exactly what's wrong, but a few ideas: 0.5 is a rather old version of the training exercises (latest is 0.9), so an upgrade might help; you could try flink.bat rather than flink.sh; and you should be able to run the sample solution in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't know why exactly, but a newer version (0.9.0) solved the problem and works for me.